# Unsure of correct method to list blobs with a SharedAccess Token

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I upgraded WindowsAzure.Storage to 4.0.3
I want to output to a webpage a list of blobs in a folder, where clicking on the link downloads the blob. As the blobs are in a secure container each URI needs a shared access signature.

I used to have:

```
var dir = Container.GetDirectoryReference(folderName);
List<IListBlobItem> blobs = dir.ListBlobs().ToList();

var blobsInFolder = new List<Uri>();
foreach (IListBlobItem listBlobItem in blobs)
{   
    var blob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(listBlobItem.Uri.ToString());      
    string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(_sasConstraints);            
    blobsInFolder.Add(new Uri(blob.Uri + sasBlobToken));    
}
return blobsInFolder;
```

This no longer works as GetBlockBlobReference no longer accepts a URI but a filename. IListBlobItem does not include the filename.

I could start chopping up the Uri to get the folder and filename

```
var blob = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(folderName + "/" + Path.GetFileName(listBlobItem.Uri.AbsolutePath));
```

...but I feel that's going the wrong way (that I shouldn't have to do this?). Can someone point me in the right way please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting `IListBlobItem` to `CloudBlockBlob`

```
foreach (IListBlobItem listBlobItem in blobs)
{   
    var blob = (CloudBlockBlob) listBlobItem;      
    string sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(_sasConstraints);            
    blobsInFolder.Add(new Uri(blob.Uri + sasBlobToken));    
}
return blobsInFolder;
```

Comment: Updated your answer. When you already have casted `listBlobItem` to a `CloudBlockBlob`, then there's no need to recreate an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`.

Comment: :) Let's delete the comments and nobody will know this ever happened :) :) :)

Comment: That's the one - so much better. Thanks Alex.